# If true: destruct Class

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I was wondering if there is a way for Python to avoid other functions in the `__init__` and go straight to the `__del__`. For e.g.

```
class API:

    Array = {"status" : False, "result" : "Unidentified API Error"}

    def __init__(self, URL):

        self.isBanned()
        print "This should be ignored."

    def isBanned(self):

        if True:
            goTo__del__()

    def __del__(self):
        print "Destructed"

API = API("http://google.com/");
```

Comment: Three questions in one. Thanks. I am trying to achieve a way of going straight to the destructor from within the isBanned() this should also ignore the print under the self.isBanned() in `__init__`.

Comment: @ConnorSimpson "I've never been a fan of exceptions" - you really should get used to them if you want to continue working with python. See also EAFP vs LBYL

Comment: Don't call `__del__`. Don't even use `__del__` unless you can explain what it does (and why it isn't called sometimes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  This is what exceptions are for.

```
class BannedSite(Exception):
    pass

class API:

    Array = {"status" : False, "result" : "Unidentified API Error"}

    def __init__(self, URL):    
        if self.isBanned(URL):
            raise BannedSite("Site '%s' is banned" % URL)
        print "This should be ignored."

    def isBanned(self, URL):
        return True
```

The exception is raised in the `__init__` method, so the assignment is never done, so the instance has no references and is immediately deleted.

Comment: I've never been a fan of exceptions but if this is the only way it's gonna' get done I best start loving them. Thanks mate!

Comment: You could also use `__new__` and return some other value (e.g. `None`) if you don't want the instance constructed, but exceptions ae the usual way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to handle this is probably to raise an exception. Something like

```
class BannedException(Exception):
    """The client is banned from the API."""

class API:
    Array = {"status" : False, "result" : "Unidentified API Error"}

    def __init__(self, URL):

        self.isBanned()
        print "This should be ignored."

    def isBanned(self):

        if True:
            raise BannedException

API = API("http://google.com/");
```

Comment: I like the idea of rising the exception in a separate method. Makes the code clearer to me.

Comment: I've never been a fan of exceptions but if this is the only way it's gonna' get done I best start loving them. Thanks mate!